# Custom fonts in Chrome 'wear off' after a while

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I'm trying to implement a self-hosted custom font into my site using this CSS I generated using Font Squirrel:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'My Font';
    src: url('http://absolute.path/to/font.eot');
    src: url('http://absolute.path/to/font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://absolute.path/to/font.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('http://absolute.path/to/font.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://absolute.path/to/font.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://absolute.path/to/font.svg#pulse_rifle_expandeexpandedIt') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }
```

This works fine on Firefox, Safari and IE 8+, but on Chrome (44.0.2403.157) and Canary (47.0.2497.0) the font seems to wear off - I make an inisgnificant change, refresh the page, and the font isn't being applied. When I revert the change, the font doesn't come back, so it isn't linked.

Comment: what kind of change?

Comment: Are you getting any error related to font in your console?

Comment: @Le'nton - Changing the width of an image, fixing typos - really small stuff.

Comment: @RaviKhandelwal - No errors at all. I'm getting a 304 on the font files in the network tab, and nothing comes up in the console.

Comment: Can you please provide the name of font you're using and facing the issue?

Comment: [Pulse Rifle Expanded Italic](http://ufonts.com/fonts/pulse-rifle-expanded-italic.html)